# Autotools complain about files compiled with different contexts

Tags: c++, c, autotools, autoconf, automake

I started getting these warnings (several pages of them). The issue is that I cannot turn `subdir-objects` on because these files are compiled from different contexts (for different binaries) and therefore there are multiple `.o` files generated from each `.c`/`.cpp` file.

```
src/scheduler.meta/Makefile.am:15: warning: source file 'base/MiscHelpers.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
src/scheduler.meta/Makefile.am:15: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: It isn't clear *why* you cannot let the object files be deposited in the same directories as their source files? If multiple object files are produced per source file, how do you presently distinguish or segregate object files that are compiled from the same source?

Comment: @MikeKinghan I don't understand what you are asking. Yes one source file is compiled from several contexts, producing multiple object files. Without `subdir-objects` the files are put into the directory where they are compiled, not into the directory of the source file. That is how the different contexts are distinguished.

Comment: @MikeKinghan If I would turn on `subdir-objects` the object files would get overwritten causing compilation errors on subsequent `make` calls. I would have to call `make clean` before each compilation.

Comment: doesn't automake automatically create unique filenames by prefixing the context? e.g. `foo-foo.o` vs `libfoo-foo.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the option, simply enable *subidr-objects* by adding the `subdir-objects` option to your `Makefile.am`. e.g.:

```
  AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects foreign
```

This will create a filesystem hierarchy of binary objects.

e.g. of your Makefile.am contains:

```
foo_SOURCES=foo.c bar/bar.c
```

then the objects generated during the build will be like

```
foo.o bar/bar.o
```

When *not* using `subdir-objects`, you would instead have

```
foo.o bar.o
```

### multiple contexts

if you want to build the same source files multiple times, you want to find a way to ensure that the binary objects get unique names.
automake does this automatically, if it thinks that the objects are compiled with different flags.
You can therefore trick it into **creating unique suffixes, by providing (dummy) FLAGS for all contexts**:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS=foo
foo_SOURCES=main.c foo.c bar/foo.c
# we need to override the *_CPPFLAGS (using the defaults) to get unique names
foo_CPPFLAGS=$(AM_CPPFLAGS)

lib_LTLIBRARIES=libfoobar.la
libfoobar_la_SOURCES=lib.c foo.c bar/foo.c
# alternatively we can override *_CFLAGS
libfoobar_la_CFLAGS=$(AM_CFLAGS)
```

This will build `foo.c` (in the root) for both "foo" and "libfoobar", without generating a conflict:

```
$ ls -1 *.o */*.o
bar/foo-foo.o
bar/libfoobar_la-foo.o
foo-foo.o
foo-main.o
libfoobar_la-foo.o
libfoobar_la-lib.o
```

Comment: That's definitely not what I see happening, the names are not unique. See here: https://github.com/CESNET/torque

Comment: @Let_Me_Be before i sift through 150MB of source-code of the torque project, would  you be so kind to point to a specific Makefile.am/... that would need subdir-objects and has multiple contexts to compile a given file in?

Comment: Well, you could just run `make && make` and see where the errors show up. But the main part is `resmom` and `server` using the same sources distinguished by the macro `PBS_MOM`.

Comment: `make` fails due to missing `libpbscache`, and frankly i don't feel like installing libpbscache just for this.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be if I add `pbs_server_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)` and `pbs_mom_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)` to the resp. Makefile.ams, i get uniquified `.o`-files, just as described in my answer.